# How to start Coroutines in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

In my application I want use **Coroutines** and use **loop fun**. 
I want when fragment go to **onDestroyView** cancel this job and when fragment go to **onResume** start this job! 
I write below codes and I can cancel this in **onDestroyView**, but I don't know how can I start again in **onResume**! 
**My codes:**

```
private val bannerJob = CoroutineScope(Main)

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        bannerJob.launch {
            repeat(REPEAT_TIME) {
                delay(DELAY_TIME)
                if (autoScrollIndex < list.size) {
                    autoScrollIndex += 1
                } else {
                    autoScrollIndex = 0
                }
                binding.list.scrollToPosition(autoScrollIndex)
            }
        }

    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        bannerJob.cancel()
    }
```

How can I start in onResume from previous position?

Comment: You need to take a look at [this](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#restart).

Answer (score 1):

You’re mixing up the difference between CoroutineScopes and Jobs. Calling `launch` starts a single coroutine which is accessed via the returned Job. You haven’t done anything with this Job. You misnamed your CoroutineScope “Job” and cancelled the whole scope. A Scope can run many jobs, but not anymore after the first time you cancel it.

Anyway, there is already a provided scope you should be using, so delete your line that declares the CoroutineScope property, and instead use `viewLifecycle.lifecycleScope.launch` to start your coroutine. If you use this, your coroutines will be *automatically* canceled in `onViewDestroyed()`

Finally, you need to think about symmetry when cancelling and restarting your coroutines. If you only cancel your coroutine in `onViewDestroyed()` then you should only be starting it in `onViewCreated()`. If you restart it in `onResume()` then you could end up with multiple copies of it running in parallel because `onResume()` can be called multiple times between the view being created and destroyed. If you do actually mean to stop your job when the view of your app is covered (a dialog pops up or user switches apps) and restart it when your app resumes, then you should be cancelling the job in the symmetrical lifecycle event to `onResume()`, which is `onPause()`.

To be able to cancel your Job at some time other than `onViewDestroyed`, you need to create a `Job?` property to assign the returned Job from the `launch` call to. Then you can call `?.cancel()` on it in `onPause()`.